# Gaining understanding and intuition on the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$, $B^A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

The text I'm using defines the set of all functions from one set $A$ to another set $B$ by:

> $B^A = \{ \sigma : A \rightarrow B \mid \sigma \text{ is a function} \}$

The text then goes on to say that the next example will clarify the notation. The next example is as follows:

> Consider the case that $A = \{1,...,n\}$ is the set of natural number between $1$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and $B$ is any set. Then we define a function $f: B^{\{1,...,n\}} \rightarrow B^n = B 
> \times \dotsm \times B$ by the equation $f(\sigma) = ( \sigma(1),...,\sigma(n))$

---

I'm having a bit of trouble seeing exactly what's going on here. Specifically, I'm having trouble understanding the domain of $f$. So, I know that $B^n$ is the set of $n$-tuples of elements of $B$, where the elements of $B$, based on the definition would be $\sigma(a)$ for $a \in A$. But understanding $f(\sigma)$ and how that connects to the way the domain ($B^{\{1,...,n\}}$) is depicted is giving me some trouble.

- So, regarding $f(\sigma)$: $\sigma$ is just a stand in for any function one can think of that would take the elements of $A$ i.e., a finite subset of the natural numbers to whatever $B$ ends up being? So that as we change the specific function $\sigma$ that we are dealing with the $n$-tuple necessarily changes as it takes the elements of $A$ to (potentially - depending on in/surjectivity, though the text claims $f$ is a bijection) different elements of $B$. So that our different elements of $B^n$ (our individual $n$-tuples) would be generated by changing the function $\sigma$?
- If this is indeed the case, I'm still having trouble interpreting the way the domain ($B^{\{1,...,n\}}$) is written. The domain of $f$ would be, it seems, the set of all the functions $\sigma$ since it is taking each one and applying it to the set of the elements of $A$ to form an  $n$-tuple of elements of $B$. Is this correct? And if so, how can I see that from the depiction of the domain in the definition of $f$?

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things. The idea is just that $f$ turns a function $\sigma:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow B$ into the tuple  in $B^n$ whose $i$th term is the value of $\sigma$ on input $i$. For instance, take $B=\mathbb{N}$ and $n=2$. Then if we feed $f$ the function "$1\mapsto 3, 2\mapsto 17$," we get out the tuple $(3,17)$. Does this make sense?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes that does make sense. So then, the domain of $f$ being written as it is, is just saying to us that the function we are using as an input for $f$ (I.e., $\sigma$) is a function from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $B$?

Comment: Exactly: $f$ is a function from a set of functions to a set of tuples.

Comment: Okay this is going to take some time to assimilate and become clear but you've gone a long way in clarifying my main issues with it. I thank you for that @NoahSchweber. I hate to ask but do you know of any other examples I could look up to help coalesce this information?

Answer (score -1):

$f$ could be rewritten as follows:

\begin{equation}
f:\sigma\mapsto (\sigma(1),\cdots,\sigma(n)).
\end{equation}

So clearly $f$ maps the function $\sigma$ from $B^{\{1,\cdots,n\}}$, to the $n$-tuples from $B^n$ which is equal to $(\sigma(1),\cdots,\sigma(n))$.

---

By the way, you can also prove that $f$ is a bijection, and so tuples could be regarded as functions.